# Passing data between web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have two different Web applications and I would like to know how to send data from my first web application to second, something like writing my name on a textbox in the first web application and show it on a label in the second web application. I've seen some code with responde.redirect, session variable, cookies, application state and server.transfer but it is always to send data to another pages in the same project. Can I use that anyway? I'm using ASP.Net with C#.

Ok..I did it. It worked for me

web app 1

```
protected void buttonPassValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:57401/WebForm1.aspx?Name=" +
            this.txtFirstName.Text + "&LastName=" +
            this.txtLastName.Text); }
```

Web app2

```
 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        this.lblname.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
        this.lbllastname.Text = Request.QueryString["Lastname"]; }
```

Comment: What about `QueryString`

Comment: Do you have access to change the code of second web site where you want data from first website?

Comment: You can get values from first website e.g on linkbutton click and pass them to other web site by make query string of those. In the receiving end you can write code to get the values from query string

Comment: ok but how can I get the values that I wrote in the first web app on the second web application?

Comment: Can you see if is correct please? @Adil

Comment: Seems okay, do you have any problems?

Comment: It's done, I forgot to put  if (!IsPostBack) in the page load. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Get` method to send data in querystring then extract values from it on receiving page.

If data needs to be secured, use `POST` method. Generate a request using `WebClient` to the url. On receiving page, extract data from `POST` variables and show on `label`.

**POST method example: (Request)**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["name"] = "Name";
    values["username"] = "username";
    var response = client.UploadValues("url of page", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```

**Read data from POST: (on target page)**

```
NameValueCollection postData = Request.Form;
string name, username;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData["name"]))
{
  name = postData["name"];
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData["username"]))
{
  username = postData["username"];
}
```

Comment: Ok..i'm trying to do it, i'm a kind of a newbie on web app

Comment: I've added sample code to send and receive data using POST method. Give it a try, its very simple.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to create web services to communicate between applications.